# Change a button's image on tap of other button inside a list view, view cell

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a `listview`. This `list view` has 5 rows with two `buttons` namely `A` & `B`. When I tap on `button A` on a `row`, I want to change the image on `A` as well as `B` on the same row and vice-versa. I am able to individually tap and change the image on the same `button` but don't know how to change the image on the other button. Here is my `listview`:

```
<ListView x:Name="GroupedView" SeparatorColor="Transparent" GroupDisplayBinding="{Binding Title}" IsGroupingEnabled="true" HasUnevenRows="true" >
                    <ListView.GroupHeaderTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <ViewCell>
                                <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" Padding="5" BackgroundColor="#E2F5F9">
                                    <Label Text="{Binding Title}" TextColor="{StaticResource NavyBlue}" />
                                </StackLayout>
                            </ViewCell>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListView.GroupHeaderTemplate>
                    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <ViewCell>
                                <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" Spacing="2" Padding="5">
                                    <StackLayout VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                                        <Label Text="{Binding QuestionName}" />
                                    </StackLayout>
                                    <StackLayout IsVisible="{Binding ShowYesNo}" Spacing="15" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalOptions="End">
                                        <Button ClassId="Yes" Clicked="ChoiceSelected" CommandParameter="{Binding question_id}" Image="{Binding YesChoiceImg}" />
                                        <Button ClassId="No" Clicked="ChoiceSelected" CommandParameter="{Binding question_id}" Image="{Binding NoChoiceImg}" />
                                    </StackLayout>
                                </StackLayout>
                            </ViewCell>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                </ListView>
```

I am then using the sender to identify the `class ID` and change the image of the button.

Should I be using a `command`? Should I be doing something else? Please help. Thanks

Comment: please post the code for ChoiceSelected

Comment: @Jason- here is the code:

`var item = sender as Button;
   if (item.ClassId.Equals("Yes")) {
                string source = item.Image as FileImageSource;
                if (source.Equals("UnCheck.png")) {
                    item.Image = "Check.png";
                } else {
                    item.Image = "UnCheck.png";
                }
            } else ....`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use the CommandParameter you should be using a Command. At the moment you're mixing 2 different ways to handle the click.

One thing to note though is that if you use a command you usually want to bind it to a Command that is defined on your ViewModel but since inside the DataTemplate your BindingContext is the ListView item instead of the ViewModel so you have to reference around that. Something like this should work:

```
<DataTemplate>
    <ViewCell>
        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" Spacing="2" Padding="5">
            <StackLayout VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                <Label Text="{Binding QuestionName}" />
            </StackLayout>
            <StackLayout IsVisible="{Binding ShowYesNo}" Spacing="15" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalOptions="End">
                <Button ClassId="Yes" Command="{Binding Path=BindingContext.ButtonCommand, Source={x:Reference MyQuestionPage}}" CommandParameter="{Binding .} Image="{Binding YesChoiceImg}" />
                <Button ClassId="No" Clicked="ChoiceSelected" CommandParameter="{Binding question_id}" Image="{Binding NoChoiceImg}" />
            </StackLayout>
        </StackLayout>
    </ViewCell>
</DataTemplate>
```

Note here that you have to give your ContentPage an x:Name (so you can reference it and call the BindingContext on it). And the `"{Binding .}"` binds to the current list item. So no need to search for it on id you can just plug it into the command directly!

Comment: Thank you @Knoop - I am able to change the images when I click the buttons using `Command` however, I have similar kinda buttons in the `listview` as well. When I change the image of one button, the other button in the same list also get updated. How do I make sure that the image get changed to the specific row that I have clicked? Do I write a `linq` ?

Comment: Good to hear you got it working! Good luck with the project