# How to pass Binding Property via Tapped Event Handler?

Tags: xaml, xamarin, mvvm, xamarin.forms

I have TapGestureRecognizer within a ListView with a Tapped Event handler.  I would like to pass to the code behind the property from a Span as follow:

XAML

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding GetCases}" HasUnevenRows="True">
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ViewCell>
                            <ViewCell.View>
                                <StackLayout Margin="20,0,20,0">
                                    <Label Text="Case Reference:" FontSize="14" TextColor="Green"/>
                                    <Label FontSize="12" TextColor="Blue" FontAttributes="Bold">
                                        <Label.FormattedText>
                                            <FormattedString>
                                                <Span Text="{Binding Ref}" TextColor="Blue" TextDecorations="Underline">
                                                    <Span.GestureRecognizers>
                                                        <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="TapGestureRecognizer_OnTapped"  NumberOfTapsRequired="1" />
                                                    </Span.GestureRecognizers>
                                                </Span>
                                            </FormattedString>
                                        </Label.FormattedText>
                                    </Label>
                                </StackLayout>
                            </ViewCell.View>
                        </ViewCell>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
```

My Event Handler  (the property Ref, is the one I want to retrieve from XAML)

```
  private void TapGestureRecognizer_OnTapped(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var tappedPost = sender as Cases;  // Cases is my model with the Ref property
        Navigation.PushAsync(new CaseViewModel(tappedPost.Ref));
    }
```

I would to retrieve the Ref property from Xaml as displayed above.  Command did not work for me, due to the ListView (I have tried it).  Only Tapped handler worked for me, but unfortunately, It does not retrieve the property.  Anyone here to help me?  Thanks.

Comment: Can you not do like (BindingContext as YourViewModel).ref , if ref is a public property?

Comment: Yes the Ref is public property.  BindingContext  didn't work for me.

Comment: ListView already has an ItemTapped event. You can get the tapped item in ItemTappedEventArgs param.

Comment: @prezequias Strange, if you have declared the `BindingContext` somewhere, this should work. Don't know why it's not working.
Also can you try 
`var span = (Span)sender;
 var vm = (YourViewModel)span.BindingContext;`

Comment: You can actually do commands from a ListView item perfectly fine: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53671688/10608418

Answer (score 2):

`sender` should be the element the `GestureRecognizer` is attached to (in your case, the `span`)

```
private void TapGestureRecognizer_OnTapped(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    var span = (Span)sender;

    var case = (Cases)span.BindingContext;

    // you could also use span.Text
    Navigation.PushAsync(new Cases(case.Ref));
}
```

Comment: Hi Json, I've got an error: "Specified cast is not valid" on (Span)sender.  any thoughts?

Comment: you might need to use the debugger to verify that type of sender - I haven't done this in a while so my recollection may be wrong

Comment: Debugging I can see the Xamarin.Forms.Span with the Text value of the Ref I need.  How can i pass this value?

Comment: As I asked before, what is the actual type of the sender object?

Comment: its a Xamarin.Forms.Label

Comment: oh, that's interesting.  Then just cast it to a Label, then cast it's BindingContext to Cases as I originally suggested