# How to get the id of the toggled switch item in the listview using xamarin forms

Tags: listview, xamarin.forms, uiswitch

I have a listview and all the listview item contain a switch at the right end like below picture.

[Listview Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JjFM9.png)

When I select an item the switch fires the Toggled event. My codes are adding below:

Xaml:

```
 <Switch IsToggled="false"  Margin="210,2,2,2" Toggled="Switch_Toggled" />
```

Xaml.cs:

```
 private void Switch_Toggled(object sender, ToggledEventArgs e)
    {
       // I need the retail_modified_item_id of the selected item, how I can access that

    }
private void accept(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
       // fetch all selected items and display success 
        DisplayAlert("Success", "Request Accepted and Updated", "OK");
    }
```

Model class:

```
namespace XamNative.Models
{

public class Human
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public int retail_modified_item_id { get; set; }
    public double old_price { get; set; }
    public double new_price { get; set; }
}
}
```

I need the retail_modified_item_id of all the selected item[item1,item2],when i click accept button ?

Comment: Have you tried casting the `sender` as Switch and then accessing it's `BindingContext`. ListView automatically sets the `BindingContext` to the item so you should be able to access it like that. That being said I'm more of a fan of using Commands and CommandParameters though in the ListView case you need to do a little work around to get it right. Something to point you in the direction: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53671688/10608418

Comment: {Binding .} is for binding the element from .cs file right ?now i want get toggled item id ..

Comment: Yes it binds the item from the `ItemsSource`, so if that item has an Id property you should be able to access that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

get the BindingContext of the switch, and from that get the ID you need

```
// list to hold all selected values
List<string> selected = new List<string>();

private void Switch_Toggled(object sender, ToggledEventArgs e)
{
   // I need the retail_modified_item_id of the selected item, how I can access that

   var switch = (Switch)sender;
   var human = (Human)switch.BindingContext;
   var id = human.retail_modified_item_id;

   // add/remove id from selected based on IsToggled
   if (switch.IsToggled) {
     if (!selected.Contains(id)) selected.Add(id);
   } else {
     if (selected.Contains(id)) selected.Remove(id);
   }
}
```

Comment: Is this id have entire selected value? how to print this ?

Comment: id will have the id.  `human` will be the entire selected object.  I'm not sure what you mean by "print"?  You can use a DisplayAlert to display a message to the user, or Console.Writeline to output it to the console.

Comment: i want all selected value but this id only returns what i selected at that time.i have to send all selected value to accept( )function

Comment: Well, then you should have asked that in your original question.  It's trivial to create an array or other data structure to maintain the list of all selected elements.  Or you could use databinding to track them in your model.

Comment: i added.i fetch the data from api so id is binding with API.. do you mean instead of id i have to create an array .. right ?but how get array length and get all values ?

Comment: I expanded my example to show how to maintain a list of all selected ids

Comment: this answer has massively helped me and my understanding of binding contexts